# Unfinished A Killed/Rollback Transaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

[image: Unfinished A Killed/Rollback Transaction]

I have killed a transaction 2 days ago but it hasn't finished yet. You can see the situation in the pic. What can i do?

Comment: what was this process doing which you killed? Can you post output of sp_whoisactive(script from Mr. Adam Machanic for checking the processes)

Comment: Possible dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213076/session-in-a-limbo-state-killed-rollback. In short, try killing the Windows process launched with `xp_cmdshell`.

Comment: @Learning_DBAdmin 07 03:48:53.543 54 <?query --
xp_cmdshell
--?> OPSS\karaca (618521455ms)PREEMPTIVE_OS_PIPEOPS         618,521,460                   0                   0 NULL                   0                   0                   0                   4 runnable                   0 NULL KARACA3 DbaTools Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query 2019-12-01 11:45:25.943 2019-12-01 11:41:20.507 0 2019-12-08 15:34:19.707

The output is complexed so much sorry. Can you get it?

Comment: @DanGuzman how can i find & kill the windows process which causes the situation?

Comment: Execute `DBCC INPUTBUFFER(54);` to see the windows command executed. Then run `taskmgr` and you should see the exe listed, running under either the SQL Server service account or xp_cmdshell proxy account. Right-click and select end task.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you very much for your help. You have solved my problem since last week! Glad that you are here. Absolutely amazing !!...